# establish a connection to the server netbeans

Tags: php, netbeans, ide, netbeans-7, netbeans-platform

I have a problem with the netbeans7.3.1 when ever I try to run my php program i get this error from the browser : `Unable to connect`

Firefox can't establish a connection to the server at `localhost:8000`.

my interpreter location is : `/usr/bin/php5`

The project configuration : PHP Built-in Web Server (running on built- in web server)
my operating system is : Ubuntu linux.

I've been having this problem for more then 6 months now, I've looked and searched everywhere but I could not find the solution for this.

Just to mention that I had another problem with the interpreter it used to ask me to locate the interpreter every time i run netbeans  , but i fixed this by installing php5.

Comment: What version of php? Built-in web server is only availabale since php 5.4

Comment: i am not sure how can i find out